# How do I show that for linearly independent set in dual is a dual of a linearly independent set?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Related: [How do I prove that a bilinear map is symmetric in the given condition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1896652/44669)

Let $X$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $X^*$ be the dual of $X$. Let $\lambda_1,....\lambda_n$ be linearly independent elements in $X^*$. Then, how do I prove that there are linearly independent elements $x_1,...,x_n$ in $X$ such that $\lambda_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear independence of such elements $x_j$ is automatic, since if $\sum c_jx_j=0$ then for all $i$ $0=\lambda_i(\sum c_jx_j)=c_i$.

For existence, consider  the map $\Lambda:X\to\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $\Lambda(x)=(\lambda_1(x),\dots,\lambda_n(x))$.  If $\Lambda$ were not surjective, there would be a nonzero functional $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ which vanishes on the image of $\Lambda$.  Such an $f$ would have the form $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\mapsto \sum c_ja_j$ for some $c_j\in\mathbb{R}$, and the fact that $f$ vanishes on the image of $\Lambda$ says exactly that $\sum c_j\lambda_j=0$.  Since the $\lambda_j$ are linearly independent, this can't happen unless $c_j=0$ for all $j$, i.e. $f=0$.

Thus $\Lambda$ is surjective.  In particular, there exist $x_j\in X$ whose images under $\Lambda$ are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  This means exactly that $\lambda_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$.