# How do I prove that a bilinear map is symmetric in the given condition?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Related: [How do I show that for linearly independent set in dual is a dual of a linearly independent set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1896646/44669)

Let $X$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ be linearly independent elements in $X^*$.

Define $X^+:=\{x\in X: \lambda_1(x)\geq 0,\ldots,\lambda_n(x)\geq 0\}$.

Let $T:X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous bilinear map such that $T(x,y)=T(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in X^+$.

How do I prove that $T(x,y)=T(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in X$?

Comment: $X^+$ is a closed convex cone. So you can decompose every $x\in X$ as $x = u - v $ with $u,v\in X^+$...

Comment: @user251257 How do I prove that?

Comment: @Tryss I still don't get it.. Could you give me some details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Go over to the quotient space of $X$ by factoring out the closed subspace $X^+ \cap (-X^+)$. 
   Then, the cone $X^+$ after factoring is a proper closed affine cone.
2. In quotient space, which is a Riesz space (vector lattice), each element admits a decomposition into difference of positive elements. Transporting the decomposition back into $X$ and exploiting the bilinearity yield the statement.