# Implicit function for quadrants of real Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, banach-spaces, banach-fixed-point, inverse-function-theorem

> **Definition 1**
>
> Let $X$ be a *real* Banach space and $X^+\subset X$.
>
> Then, $X^+$ is called a **quadrant** of $X$ iff there exists a nonempty finite linearly independent subset $\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\}$ of continuous linear functionals on $X$ such that $X^+=\{x\in X: \forall 1\leq i \leq n, \lambda_i(x)\geq 0\}$.

=

> Definition 2
>
> Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $E$ be a subset of $X$ and $p\in E$ be a limit point of $E$.
>
> Let $f:E\rightarrow W$ be a function.
>
> Then, $f$ is said to be (Fréchet) **differentiable at $p$** iff there exists a continuous linear transformation $T:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $\lim_{x\to p} \frac{||f(x)-f(p)-T(x-p)||}{||x-p||} =0$.
>
> (Note that differentiability can be defined at a point which is a limit point of the domain of the function)

Let $X,Y$ be *real* Banach spaces and $X^+,Y^+$ be quadrants of of $X,Y$ respectively, and $E$ be open in $X^+$.

Let $f:E\rightarrow Y^+$ be a (Fréchet) $C^1$-function and let $a\in E$ such that $Df(a)$ is invertible.

Then, how do I prove that there are open sets $V$ and $W$ in $X^+$ and $Y^+$ respectively such that $a\in V\subset E$ and $f(V)=W$ and $f\upharpoonright V: V\rightarrow W$ is a diffeomorphism?

I know how to prove the inverse function theorem for functions whose domains are open in real or complex Banach spaces. However, all those proofs I know depend on Banach contraction principle, and I have a trouble to apply the contraction principle in the given case above. I don't know whether the statement is true, but I certainly believe that it must be true.

I think my previous posts should be used to prove this, and belows are the lists:

1. [How do I show that for linearly independent set in dual is a dual of a linearly independent set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1896646/44669)
2. [Show that quadrants are homeomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1899505/44669)

Thank you in advance.